# jquery-validation on Meteor

Tags: jquery, validation, meteor

I'm trying jquery-validation package according to the site
https://atmospherejs.com/themeteorchef/jquery-validation

1. Make test project. (meteor create test)
2. Copy & Pasete the codes to my files. (test.js , test.html)
3. Add the package. (meteor add themeteorchef:jquery-validation)
4. Run. (meteor run)

And I got an error message in console like below.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Template.exampleForm.rendered is not a function"

Could you tell me why the codes doesn't work ?

Actually I add a code `"console.log($("#validation-example"))"` and search `'validate'` method in console, but I couldn't find it in the object `"$("#validation-example")".`

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem (or at least add more code to your question)? I created a demo application, installed the package and I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't say that i add a line to the file 'test.html' in <head>part like below.

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

Remove this line, and the code work as expected with no error.

But I need to use jQuery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use [`onRendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) as of meteor v1.1 (instead of the deprecated `rendered` property):

```
Template.exampleForm.onRendered(function () {
  // place your code here
  console.log("exampleForm is rendered");
});
```

For history purposes, here is the old version's way. Notice how we *assign* a function to it and not call `rendered()`:

```
Template.exampleForm.rendered = function () {
  // place your code here
  console.log("exampleForm is rendered");
};
```